# how can i get scope description in laravel passport

Tags: laravel, oauth-2.0, laravel-5.3

Using laravel passport for token base authentication. i have set up scope for
access token and now on controller i wanted to get the scope value and its   description.

```
protected function authenticate(Request $request)
{
    $request->request->add([
        'username' => $request->username,
        'password' => $request->password,
        'grant_type' => 'password',
        'client_id' => $this->client->id,
        'client_secret' => $this->client->secret,
        'scope' => 'admin'
    ]);

    $proxy = Request::create(
        'oauth/token',
        'POST'
    );

    $data =  Route::dispatch($proxy);
    //$data = json_decode($data);
    return $data;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

late to the party (I was looking this up myself) but check out the `Passport::tokensCan` array. You can define scopes and scope descriptions in there.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/passport#defining-scopes